# LaTeX doc package document keys for keyval package

Tags: margins, indexing, dtx, doc

I am trying to document a package that uses keyval for key/value argument parsing.

I wish to document the key/value options for some of the commands in the same way that I document macros and environments. I know I could just use an environment, but I'm not sure what the side-effects would be.

Here is my example:

```
%\begin{environment}{x}
% x represents the x value
%    \begin{macrocode}
\define@key{mymacro@x}{x}{\def\mymacro@x{#1}}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{environment}
```

While this looks fine in-place, it ends up under the environment section of the index, and I'm not sure if there would be other side-effects.

Is there any way to typeset a similarly documented entity, but control where it goes in the index, rather than have it appear under environments?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of a hacky solution based on the documentation of the doc package. I'm not sure how well it works, as I don't fully understand everything I've copied from its documentation, but here is what I am using:

```
% \makeatletter
% \def\DescribeKey{\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters\Describe@Key}
% \def\Describe@Key#1{\endgroup\marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeKey{#1}}\SpecialKeyIndex{#1}\@esphack\ignorespaces}
% \def\PrintDescribeKey#1{\strut \MacroFont #1\ }
% \def\SpecialKeyIndex#1{\@bsphack
%     \index{#1\actualchar{\protect\ttfamily#1}(key)\encapchar usage}^^A
%     \index{keys:\levelchar#1\actualchar{\protect\ttfamily#1}\encapchar usage}\@esphack}
% \def\keyvalue{\begingroup\catcode`\\12\MakePrivateLetters\m@cro@key@}
% \long\def\m@cro@key@#1{\endgroup\topsep\MacroTopsep\trivlist
%     \edef\saved@macroname{\string#1}^^A
%     \let\saved@indexname\saved@macroname
%     \def\makelabel##1{\llap{##1}}^^A
%     \if@inlabel
%         \let\@tempa\@empty \count@\macro@cnt
%         \loop \ifnum\count@>\z@
%             \edef\@tempa{\@tempa\hbox{\strut}}\advance\count@\m@ne \repeat
%         \edef\makelabel##1{\llap{\vtop to\baselineskip{\@tempa\hbox{##1}\vss}}}^^A
%         \advance \macro@cnt \@ne
%     \else \macro@cnt\@ne \fi
%     \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\item[^^A
%         \noexpand\PrintKeyName{\string#1}]}^^A
%     \@tempa
%     \global\advance\c@CodelineNo\@ne
%     \SpecialMainKeyIndex{#1}\nobreak
%     \global\advance\c@CodelineNo\m@ne
%     \ignorespaces}
% \let\endkeyvalue\endmacro
% \def\PrintKeyName#1{\strut \MacroFont #1\ }
% \def\SpecialMainKeyIndex#1{\@bsphack^^A
%     \special@index{#1\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#1} (key) \encapchar main}^^A
%     \special@index{keys:\levelchar#1\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#1}\encapchar main}\@esphack}
% \makeatother
```

Should allow for `\DescribeKey`, `\begin{keyvalue}{...}` as per macro and env.

Comment: This implementation is very practical ... but it is not compatible with the `hypdoc` package. The `dtxdescribe` package provides among others the command `\DescribeKey` (compatible with `hypdoc`) but does not provide the `key` (or `keyvalue`) environment.